# Android Facebook SDK WebDialog setTheme method not working

Tags: android, android-facebook

I'm using a RequestDialogBuilder in the Facebook SDK to build a WebDialog which sends some invites to Facebook friends.

One of the methods of the builder is setTheme, which takes in an int (res id) to change the theme you are using.

By default, the loading dialog looks like this:

[image: bad]

I want newer phones to use a holo theme, so I did the following:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    builder.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
```

Simple enough. But while the loading screen corrects itself:

[image: ok...]

the built dialog looks like this

[image: oops]

what it should look like, is this:

[image: whatever]

I also tried using a ContextThemeWrapper:

```
Context context = this;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    context = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
```

Then using that context to construct the RequestDialogBuilder, but that didn't work either.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use regular theme, not the one for `Dialog` (i.e., instead of `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog`, try using `android.R.style.Theme_Holo`).

When you use one of `xxx_Dialog` themes, window height is set to `wrap_content`. This is why you see only 'X' button.